# Accidentally disabled Visual Studio Intellisense Method Param Info Tooltip

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I Accidentally disabled Visual Studio Intellisense Method Param Info Tooltip.

I tried using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> Neither of which work

How do I re-enable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the tools options, you can check if your paranthesis is missing.

[image]

Comment: Did this solve your problem? You can do a clean re-install if you have many plugins or custom things that broke the system.

Comment: `+1` for being fastest gun `:)`

Comment: Can someone throw a +1 my way? Idk why this got down voted... There are a ton of questions identical to this on Stack that get 50+ up votes

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't know why <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> didn't work but you can change it following;

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense -> Commited by typing the following characters.
```

Make you you have `()` in these characters.

Als you can download [Visual C# 2010 Keybinding Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13189)